# IE screenshot problem in c# windows service

Tags: c#, windows, internet-explorer, service

I am using win 2003 server.

I have windows service created in c# .net, it opens IE at every 5 min with predefined URL, get screen shot of it and save it to database. It seems a simple application. But my problem is, when machine is lock (window key + l) or machine is logged off, IE process is start, but cant take screen-shot, it takes "black page" only.

Is there any option to run IE at login screen? or is there any work around of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As posted in [Generate WebPage Thumbmail Screenshot Image](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/07/C-Generate-WebPage-Thumbmail-Screenshot-Image.aspx) you could try using a WebBrowser control in your service and generating a screenshot from that.

Comment: thanks CodeCanvas.

But, i need whole IE screen-shot, the way mention in your solution is capturing screen-shot only of web page, i need whole IE screen-shot.

Any solution regarding this?

Comment: @Ankit: Sorry, I am not aware of any method using which we can take a screen shot of an application that is running inside a locked windows session.

Answer (score 0):

The service needs to run with the "interact with desktop" check box ticked. The window needs to be upper-most in the Z-Order when the screen shot is taken and not overlapped by other windows. This approach is quite error prone...as I have found.

Answer (score 0):

To interact with desktop using code:

Put this just before you start the service.

```
String sYourServiceName = @"MyService" //Change this to r service name
ConnectionOptions co = new ConnectionOptions(); 
co.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate; 
ManagementScope mgmtScope = new System.Management.ManagementScope(@"root\CIMV2", co); 
mgmtScope.Connect(); 
ManagementObject wmiService; 
wmiService = new ManagementObject("Win32_Service.Name='" + sYourServiceName + "'"); 
ManagementBaseObject InParam = wmiService.GetMethodParameters("Change"); 
InParam["DesktopInteract"] = true; 
ManagementBaseObject OutParam = wmiService.InvokeMethod("Change", InParam, null);
```

or

Try to run `iexplore` "Internet explorer" as a system account from the logon page.  Just execute `Process.Start("Iexplore.exe")` from your Windows service and it should work, but I am not sure if you can execute `iexplore` as a system level account.

Otherwise,  you can try to block the lockout screen by writing a basic key grabber or a key logger to block `MENU+L` lockout, you can do this by enabling interaction with desktop. I posted the code to make it easier or do it manually by going to services and clicking on your service. There you should see a checkbox with the text `interact with desktop`.

//M